# Make USB Printer Canon E400 wirless using Bluetooth adapter, cables

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, printer, bluetooth

Using bluetooth, I want to make my [Canon E400 printer](http://www.canon.com.my/personal/products/inkjet-printers/inkjet-multi-function/pixma-e400?languageCode=EN) wireless. Is it possible?

Adapter Buying: [USB Bluetooth Stereo Music Receiver 3.5mm Adapter Dongle For Speakers Car MP3](http://www.ebay.in/itm/331867019656?aff_source=Sok-Goog#shpCntId)

AUX to USB Female, which will be connected to my printer, as it had USB male which I generally connect to my PC ([link](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Audio-Converter-Cable-3-5mm-Male-Jack-to-Female-USB-MP3-Car-AUX-Adapter-Lead-/181465161997?hash=item2a402aa10d:g:X4IAAOSwGzlTw0z6))

So, I will connect my USB printer to AUX of (AUX to USB Male cable) which will be connecting to Bluetooth Receiver AUX port, and will put Bluetooth receiver to power adapter.

Will it work? The print servers are over $50 but this will be $6 only.

I will be using the USB Bluetooth Stereo Music Receiver 3.5mm Adapter Dongle For Speakers Car MP3 for connected my phone to Car music system, which is not wireless.

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE:

If this is no possible will some Wireless N Nano router can work with my usb printer. I was able to use the same one with thermal printer network port but my printer just have USB??

Comment: Yep, quite a challenge is here... The printer is "USB **Device**", it accepts **digital serial stream**, and requires a USB host PC to provide it. The BT is a reciever that produces Audio **analog signal** from a BT host, to drive speakers or car audio. Ask yourself, who on the Earth will transform analog music into printer's rasterisated pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PC will not be able to communicate with the printer via a Bluetooth Music receiver. The driver will not see it.

There may be some printserver that works with your printer, but be careful. The Canon E400 is a GDI (host-based) printer, which relies on the PC's graphics engine to convert a page into dots on the page. These printers are hard to network. They work fine if shared from a PC, or networked via their own built-in network interface.

They can also be networked using a printserver, but **only** if the printserver supports it. Reputable manufacturers provide "printer support lists" for their devices. If your GDI printer is not on the list, you can be certain it will **not work**.

Then same goes for wireless routers. Some of those have a USB port for a printer, but you **must** check that it supports your printer. They will work fine with most thermal printers as these printers are not GDI printers, but support a printer language like ZPL or ESC/P.